# Jest mock dimensions not changing

Tags: typescript, react-native, testing, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I am doing testing for the first time so I am pretty much sure that I am doing something wrong.

I was writing test case and my component does this internally.

```
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')
```

For my test case, I was considering iPhone 11 which have dimensions as `width: 414, height:896`, and I want this consistent across all the test cases.

React native testing library while testing sets width as `750` and height as `1334`.

I want to change it to iPhone 11 dimensions, I searched web and found articles which uses `jest.mock` to change function.

So I did something like this

```
it('renders correctly', () => {
     jest.mock("Dimensions", () => ({
        get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ width: 414, height:896 }),
     }))
      
     const {getByTestId} = render(<Home />)
```

`Home` component have `console.log(width, height)` but it is still giving width as 750 and height as 1334 (because of which my test case is failing).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to mock `Dimensions.get` return value on a per-test basis, you can create the following mock function with [`jest.doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).

```js
const mockDimensions = ({ width, height }) => {
    jest.resetModules()
    jest.doMock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Dimensions', () => ({
        get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ width, height })
    }))
}
```

Then call it at the beginning of your tests as follows.

```js
it('renders correctly', () => {
    mockDimensions({ width: 414, height: 896 })  
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Home />)
    // Your assertions
})
```

`jest.doMock` is used instead of `jest.mock` to avoid hoisting, which allows us to mock the dimensions on each test rather than globally.

Comment: This works for `ios` but for some reason it fails in a `web` environment, when making use of `react-native-web`,  I'm using with `jest-expo` config

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me for ios

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

 jest.spyOn(Dimensions, 'get').mockReturnValue({ width: 414, height: 818 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the test, we override the screen width returned by Dimensions

```
  const Dimensions = jest.requireActual(
    "react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Dimensions"
  );

  return {
    ...Dimensions,
    get: (param) => {
      if (param === "window") {
        return {
          width: 310,
        };
      }
    },
  };
});
```